# Сбрасывается содержимое модального окна в ASP.NET Core

Tags: ajax, asp.net-core, modal

Есть ссылка которая должна открывать модальное окно, она его открывает но после перезагрузки страницы модальное окно проподает.[image: Модальное окно]
[image: Модальное окно после перезагрузки страницы]

```
 <a class="link" href="#modalAdd" onclick="AddView()">Добавить поставщика</a>

<!-- Модальное окно для добавления -->
<div id="modalAdd" class="modal">
    <div id="modalAddContent" class="modal-dialog"></div>
</div>
<!-- /Модальное окно для добавления -->

<script type="text/javascript">

    function AddView(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Handbooks/Suppliers/AddPartialView", // Подгружает содержимое модального окна
            contentType: "application/text; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "text",
            success: function (data){
                $('#modalAddContent').html(data);
            }
        })
    };
</script>
```